# ./configure throwing error with ssldump code base

Tags: c++, makefile, configure

Was trying to work with ssldump 
got the code from  http://www.rtfm.com/ssldump/ssldump-0.9b3.tar.gz

and followed the instruction from INSTALL 
but

```
./configure
```

is throwing

```
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

checking target system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

checking build system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine `x86_64-unknown' not recognized

checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) works... yes
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) is a cross-compiler... no
checking whether we are using GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking whether make sets ${MAKE}... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for a BSD compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
configuring for
checking for pow in -lm... yes
checking for PCAP include files... found in /usr/include
checking for PCAP library...
configure: error: Couldn't find PCAP library: needed for ssldump
```

and then I tried

```
./configure --with-pcap-lib /usr/lib64/libpcap.so --with-pcap-inc /usr/include/pcap
```

but getting this error.

```
configure: warning: /usr/lib64/libpcap.so: invalid host type
configure: warning: /usr/include/pcap: invalid host type
configure: error: can only configure for one host and one target at a time
```

and then

```
./configure --enable-64bit=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-pcap-lib /usr/lib64/libpcap.so --with-pcap-inc /usr/include/pcap

configure: warning: /usr/lib64/libpcap.so: invalid host type
configure: warning: /usr/include/pcap: invalid host type
configure: error: can only configure for one host and one target at a time
```

and I tried all those with commands with updated .sub and .guess files but still no luck.

Comment: `--enable-64bit` isn't a valid option as far as I see. You probably want `--host` if it cannot guess yours

Comment: i tried that, but still same errors

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install build-essential openssl libssl-dev curl vim ca-certificates git libpcap0.8-dev libpcap0.8

./configure --prefix=/ --with-pcap-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

make && make install
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful if you could explain why your code would solve the problem.